# Loading freezes after removing nvidia graphics card

Tags: 18.04, graphics

I want to switch to integrated Intel graphics with my computer and remove the Nvidia graphics card completely. It's an HP desktop running Ubuntu 18.04. When I remove the card I can see the Ubuntu loading screen but it freezes, even the mouse stops moving. The freeze happens right after the mouse cursor appears.

When I started in recovery mode I was able to see the login screen. It freezed again after entering my password.

I thought initially the issue is having Nvidia drivers installed. But even after uninstalling these with `apt purge nvidia*` nothing changed.

When I put the Nvidia graphics card back everything works fine.

I'd like to know what it might be and how to debug the issue. I'm pretty sure reinstalling the OS would help but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

**Edit:**

So far I have switched to `lightdm` - `gdm3` will always freeze, depending on grub configuration either before or after login. Thanks @heynnema

I have edited grub at startup to remove `quiet splash` and added `nomodeset`. If `spash` is there or `nomodeset` is not the login screen will freeze or I get a black screen. Thanks @heynnema

Also at grub startup I have to remove the `gfxmode` line to get good performance. Figured that one out by comparing grub setup for normal and recovery mode.

I followed [how to restore default graphic driver configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530574/how-to-restore-default-graphic-driver-configuration) to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with `Section "Device" Identifier "Card0" Driver "intel" Option "AccelMethod" "sna" EndSection`. With that and not using `nomodeset` I don't get black screens but the login screen will always freeze.

By making `nomodeset` and `gfxmode` permament in grub I could have a perfectly working computer. I understand however that it's a hacky solution and not recommended.

Output of `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`:

```
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
```

I have since removed both packages, made no difference.

**Edit 2:**

I have now installed Windows 10 without issues. So the combination of my new setup and Ubuntu is never going to work properly.

In case anyone cares about the hardware setup, according to Speccy the CPU is an i7 3770K with Intel HD Graphics 4000 and the motherboard is PEGATRON CORPORATION 2AD5. I've installed 32 GB DDR3 RAM.

I'm going to switch computers soon and try Ubuntu on very similar hardware. If that also fails I might have to stick to Windows... which would suck.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

- boot to recovery mode
- choose root access

type:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /      # to remount the disk r/w

sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf # edit this file
```

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then reboot.

**Update #1:**

<strike>Edit your GRUB boot command, find "quiet splash" and change it to "nomodeset", and see if it boots. The resolution will be off. If it freezes, observe the text you'll see on the screen for clues as to why it's freezing.</strike>

**Update #2:**

Lets try and change the display manager.

Boot into Recovery Mode, root access.

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /`      # to remount the disk r/w

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` # choose lightdm

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Note**: later, if you need to switch back to gdm3 display manager...

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` # switch back to gdm3

Comment: It is old, from 2013. That did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Edit your GRUB boot command, find "quiet splash" and change it to "nomodeset", and see if it boots. The resolution will be off. If it freezes, observe the text you'll see on the screen for clues as to why it's freezing. Report back.

Comment: Now I get to the same place as with recovery mode. After entering my password all I see is violet, the entire screen, no text.

Comment: See my answer, Update #2. Report back.

Comment: I didn't have lightdm so I installed it. Now I can get to the desktop! But only using recovery mode or nomodeset. Normal boot takes me to an all black screen and freezes. Can I make nomodeset permanent or is there something else I can do?

Comment: You should probably search here on AU for "black screen", and you'll get a number of hits that might help you more than I can at this point. nomodeset can be set permanently but it would limit resolution. Please keep me posted on how you make out, ok?

Comment: @rinu I just thought of something... would you be trying to boot to the -14 or -45 kernel? If so, try booting an older kernel and see if it boots.

Comment: I have 4.15.0-45 and 4.15.0-42. Both do the same. I will look for more info on the black screen.

Comment: Permanent nomodeset and reinstalling are the only options I have found. Using nomodeset gets me full resolution but incredibly slow graphics. I have also attempted reinstalling xorg and ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @rinu  Show me `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`. Edit this output into your question, then ping me at @heynnema

Comment: I have edited the question @heynnema

Comment: @rinu thanks for the update. Did we ever try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to see if that would work properly with your Intel video? If it does, you may just wish to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Booting from live USB doesn't work. If I click Try or Install then everything freezes. If I wait the computer just turns off.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the entire computer with very similar specs and from the same era, no more issues. Ubuntu simply doesn't work with that 2013 HP ENVY Phoenix desktop hardware after removing the dedicated graphics card.